# calling externalinterface.call from embedded swf from another server is not working in Firefox

Tags: flash, externalinterface

I have an index.html on server A.

In index.html I embed a swf from server B.

The swf contains a init with 
flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("alert", "externalalert");

When I run the swf on server B it works, when I run the swf through the index.html on server A I get an : Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller...

It does work in IE.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The fix is to add

```
System.security.allowDomain("*");
```

in your AS code. `ExternalInterface` requires the `allowDomain` to be set when HTML-SWF cross-scripting is performed.

Note that you will also need to set `allowScriptAccess="always"` in the swf embed tags to allow cross-scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. This is a restriction of the Flash player. Interacting between different domains is not allowed. You could try to use a `crossdomain.xml`. (But I do not know if this works you `ExternalInterfaces`).
More Information can be found here:

- [Flash Player Security @ Adobe Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=05B_Security_176_01.html)
- [Overview of permission controls - website controls @ Adobe Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=05B_Security_176_03.html#122782)